# Including MongoDB entries as EJS tags

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm working on a hobby project and I would need to include four random objects out of a database collection into my rendered .ejs file.

Here's what I have on the server side:

```js
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  Entry.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 4 } } ],function(err, entry){ //get four random entries from DB
   if(err){
    console.log(err)
   } else {
    res.render("app", {entries:entries}) //render application file
   }
  })
});
```

What I want the end result to look like is this:

```html
<div class="container">
 <h2>Hints</h2>
    <div>
      <%= randomentry1.hint %>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <%= randomentry2.hint %>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <%= randomentry3.hint %>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <%= randomentry4.hint %>
    </div>
 </div>
 

<div class="container">
 <h2>Answer</h2>
    <div>
      <%= randomentry1.answer %>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <%= randomentry2.answer %>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <%= randomentry3.answer %>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <%= randomentry4.answer %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already managed to access the extracted entries in my .ejs file by just printing them out using entries.forEach. I don't know how to access them individually though.

Any help is appreciated

Note: I'm working on nodeJS using mongoDB